# Custom Admin Creation Form

Tags: django, django-admin

So in my models I have a specfic profile that has a one to one relationship with a more general profile that has a one to one relationship with the django user model. I want to be able to fill out one form in the django admin and create instances of all three models, with relationships already set up.

I haven't messed around with the django admin too much, so I'm not entirely sure how to make it work. Here is my failed attempt:

```
class CreateSpecializedProfileAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['profile']

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if len(self.cleaned_data['password']) < 6:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password must be at least 6 characters.')
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords must match.')
        return super(CreateSpecializedProfileAdminForm, self).clean()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        first = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)
        user.first_name = first
        user.last_name = last
        user.save()
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user_auth = user
        profile.save()
        specialized_profile = SpecializedProfile()
        specialized_profile.profile = profile
        specialized_profile.save()
        return specialized_profile

class SpecializedProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

form = CreateSpecializedProfileAdminForm

admin.site.register(SpecializedProfile, SpecializedProfileAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

remove `class Meta` and move `exclude = ['profile']` to `ModelAdmin`

```
class SpecializedProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['profile']
    form = CreateSpecializedProfileAdminForm
```